# Custom theme variant based on custom prop -- passed custom prop to div

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, themes, styled-components

I've been building a theme where I define different variants of several components, there are cases where I'd like to add an additional prop to define a completely different functionality and/or when the component doesn't currently support variants, for example on a `Dialog` with a `detailView` custom prop.

I have these definitions

```
const Dialog = (theme: Theme): Components<Theme>['MuiDialog'] => ({
  variants: [
    {
      props: { detailView: true },
      style: {
        /* some styles */
      },
    },
  ],
})

export default Dialog

declare module '@mui/material/Dialog' {
  interface DialogProps {
    detailView?: boolean
  }
}
```

however ... when I get to use the `<Dialog detailView />` variant, I get these errors

```
Warning: React does not recognize the `detailView` prop on a DOM element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom attribute, spell it as lowercase `detailview` instead. If you accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove it from the DOM element.
    at div
```

I know you can prevent custom props to be passed down from custom components to actual HTML or existing components, but how can I do so without creating a custom styled component and keep using the custom theme using default components as in `<Dialog detailView />` ?

Haven't found any doc regarding that, only extending the current theme but nothing regarding preventing custom props to be passed down using only "theming" and not styled components